# JPA in Play framework - Many to Many with extra column - not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, many-to-many, playframework-evolutions

i`m trying to create many to many relation ship with extra column using JPA in play framework (evolutions is enabled) and play version is 2.4.6 using JavaJpa hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.5 final.

here is my sql script to create all the table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_level` (
`level_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`level` int(3),
`level_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`level_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
`menu_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`menu_name` varchar(255),
`parent` bigint(20),
 PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_PARENT_MENU` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `menu` (`menu_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu_level` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`level_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`menu_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`privilege` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_MENU_LEVEL_USER_LEVEL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`level_id`) REFERENCES `user_level` (`level_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_MENU_LEVEL_MENU_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_id`) REFERENCES `menu` (`menu_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

below are my entity classes

**UserLevel.java**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "user_level")
public class UserLevel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @Column(name = "level_id")
  private Long levelId;

  @Column(name = "level")
  private Integer level;

  @Column(name = "level_name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userLevel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<MenuLevel> menuLevels;
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="menu")
public class Menu  {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @Column(name = "menu_id")
  private Long menuId;

  @Column(name = "menu_name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<MenuLevel> menuLevels;

/*parent child menu relations*/
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
  private List<Menu> childMenu = new ArrayList<>();

  @JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName = "menu_id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Menu parent;

}
```

**MenuLevel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu_level")
public class MenuLevel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  public Long id;

  @JoinColumn(name = "level_id", referencedColumnName = "level_id")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private UserLevel userLevel;

  @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id", referencedColumnName = "menu_id")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Menu menu;

  @Column(name = "privilege")
  private Integer privilege;
}
```

when i running play, it is said

***Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException:    referencedColumnNames(menu_id) of models.MenuLevel.menu referencing   models.Menu not mapped to a single property***

at this time i stuck with this problem, very happy if someone can point out my mistake, because i have followed some tutorial and instruction about JPA many to many relationship but still cant figuring out where i do wrong.

Comment: FWIW "referencedColumnName" is of no use at all when you have a single column PK ... it always uses the "PK" column of the related object, so just omit those.

Comment: yes, at first i`m aware of that, but when doesnt define "referenceColumnName" hibernate do not know where the FK referring into , the error message: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering models.Menu from models.MenuLevel has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Comment: Where is your `@Id` field(s) on MenuLevel?

Comment: corrected the sample code, thx @NeilStockton

Comment: currently  my entity extends some base entity that only injecting JPA entity manager

Comment: All your errors show that you have 2 columns primary key in Menu table. Let try to leave table generation to hibernate using **-Dhibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**.